# Creating a graph from random matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, graph

I have a problem with one exercise namely:
I need to create directed graph with random weights, 10 vertices and 45 edges (of course, the edges may be less) from the matrix (matrix is ​​formed on a `randi (n + 3, n)`,  wherein n is a number between `1 -29`).

For example

```
n = randi ([1.29], [1,1])
Randi A = (n + 3, n)
digraph (A);
plot (A);
```

And here I stopped because I did not know how to fix my graph to had these 10 vertices and 45 edges.
The number of vertices is about 15, and the edge of 90-120

Please, any tips

Comment: What is this `randi([1,29])` ? If you have 10 vertices so your Matrix will be  10x10. Simply create a matrix with random weight where the lower triangular part has no common part with the upper triangular part.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do or what you're trying to fix. Your code doesn't do anything because of errors, so that doesn't give me any clues. Please clarify with examples and executable code.